# How much should I practice trumpet to regain competency?

Tags: practice, trumpet

I used to play trumpet in band during school (2001-2006), and I haven't played with any regularity since about 2009. I recently was given a trumpet that happened to come with a beginner band book.

How much should I practice to regain competency, and what should my progression plan look like?

Comment: Questions like this always depend on factors we don't know, so any answer will be a mater of opinion. You need to practice as much as you can. How fast you progress will depend on how much you practice, whether you practice the right things, the level you reached previously  and how talented you are.

Comment: @PiedPiper thanks for that consideration and context here on why this might not be the right question to ask.

Comment: A trumpet, a method book, and the motivation to play are three important "legs" on a chair.  Don't forget about the fourth leg: a good teacher.  Get yourself some lessons.  In person is best, but nowadays lots of private teachers will teach you over zoom, too.  As an educator myself I can attest that the students who are motivated AND take private lessons advance much more quickly.  I'd start at your school, and don't be ashamed to have stopped playing for a while.  They'll probably be thrilled to have you playing again, even if you take a while to get back in shape.  Music is forgiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every day for as long as your chops hold out, which will probably be only 20-40 minutes (maximum) the first days.

As your chops come back, practice longer until you no longer have the time each day to practice for longer periods.

No matter what, practice every single day for as long as you can, even if it’s only five minutes. That’s the only way to get it back and then improve.

A progression plan is a more complicated, personalized thing. I don’t think a good answer to that would fit in a reasonable SE answer. If you can develop your own then do that. Otherwise this is one benefit of a teacher. Having taught myself and had teachers, I can say only the worst teachers are not worth the money. If you really want to get it back ASAP, a teacher is the way.